# Group with ActiveRecord and Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, group-by

I've seen several answers, but couldn't find anything that helps me

I have a Model which has a `country` column and a `city` column.

doing some SQL query, I want to add to that query a group by first country and for each country to group by city

```
Model.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%").group(["country", "city"])
```

but I get

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "models.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

and I am not sure what to do, since I don't want to group by the ID, just by country and city

I am sure I am missing something here, not sure what

using the fields, as suggested with

```
 Model.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%").group("country, city").select("country, city")
```

still gives the same error

Comment: Error is saying - what you should do. Try this `Model.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%").group("country, city").select("name, city")`. While you will be using `group by`, in any DB, you must need to use those columns which you have used in your `group by` clause, into the `select` clause too.

Comment: I get the same error even if I do `Model.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%").group(["country", "city"]).select("id")`

Comment: You see, what I put inside the `select` method.

Comment: sorry _typo_.. It will be `select("country, city")` instead of `select("name, city")`.

Comment: still gives the same error

Comment: What is your final query and error? Update your question with the information I asked.

Comment: Try with `select`, then `where` then `group` as: `Model.select('country, city').where(...`

Answer (score 4):

You should select before grouping

```
Model.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
     .select("country, city")
     .group("country, city")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still have troubles with:

```
Model.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%").group("country, city").select("country, city")
```

I guess you have defined a default scope, and you must do this way:

```
Model.unscoped.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%").group("country, city").select("country, city")
```

Edited:

If it didn't works, you can do this and publish the output:

```
Model.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%").group(["country", "city"]).to_sql
```